# how to get unique value from multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have a multidimensional arrary.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => FEMFAT
            [VERSION] => 5.1
            [VENDOR] => MAGNAECS
            [END] => 2015-01-30
            [USED_LICENSES] => 1
            [TOTAL_LICENSES] => 1
            [DENIED_LICENSES] => 0
        )
[1] => Array
    (
        [NAME] => FEMFAT
        [VERSION] => 5.1
        [VENDOR] => MAGNAECS
        [END] => 2015-01-30
        [USED_LICENSES] => 0
        [TOTAL_LICENSES] => 1
        [DENIED_LICENSES] => 0
    )
```

from the above array i want the output like below. if name is same remaining values added to first array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => FEMFAT
            [VERSION] => 5.1
            [VENDOR] => MAGNAECS
            [END] => 2015-01-30
            [USED_LICENSES] => 1
            [TOTAL_LICENSES] => 2
            [DENIED_LICENSES] => 0
        )
```

What I've tried:

```
$newArr = array(); 
foreach ($featureInfo as $val) { 
    $newArr[$val['NAME']] = $val; 
} 
$featureInfo = array_values($newArr);
```

Comment: no attempts? `foreach` loop is a start

Comment: I think this is pretty straightforward. You can iterate over each array element, compare the first one to the rest, if the name matches, then write conditional statements and do your replacement operations.

Comment: $newArr = array();
  foreach ($featureInfo as $val) {
          $newArr[$val['NAME']] = $val;
                         
  }
  $featureInfo = array_values($newArr);

if i tried this way i am geeting unique value but i want to add total_licenses to that value.

Comment: @Aniket please give me one example.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, push the whole array when its not yet set on the new container, if already set, then just add them:

```
$newArr = [];
foreach($array as $value) {
    if(!isset($newArr[$value['NAME']])) { // if this name is not yet inside, push it
        $newArr[$value['NAME']] = $value;
    } else { // if already inside then add
        $newArr[$value['NAME']]['USED_LICENSES'] += $value['USED_LICENSES'];
        $newArr[$value['NAME']]['TOTAL_LICENSES'] += $value['TOTAL_LICENSES'];
        $newArr[$value['NAME']]['DENIED_LICENSES'] += $value['DENIED_LICENSES'];
    }
}

// $newArr = array_values($newArr); // optional array reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

Ghost's answer with [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
// where $data is your original array
$final = array_values(array_reduce($data, function ($prev, $curr) {
    if (isset($prev[$curr['NAME']])) {
        $prev[$curr['NAME']]['USED_LICENSES'] += $curr['USED_LICENSES'];
        $prev[$curr['NAME']]['TOTAL_LICENSES'] += $curr['TOTAL_LICENSES'];
        $prev[$curr['NAME']]['DENIED_LICENSES'] += $curr['DENIED_LICENSES'];
    } else {
        $prev[$curr['NAME']] = $curr;
    }

    return $prev;
}, array()));
```